# Trying to free reallocated memory gives free(): invalid pointer

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, realloc

I can't figure out why I am getting the error `free(): invalid pointer` when running this code. I thought `p` is going to point to a block of memory set aside for the structures, so I am trying to free pointers beginning from the `p` e.g. `p+1`, but this is no good. What am I missing here?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct s {
    int x;
    
};
int main()
{
    struct s *p = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if ((p = realloc(p, (i+1) * sizeof(struct s))) != NULL) {
            struct s x = {.x=i*10};
            *(p+i) = x;
            
        } else exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {printf("%d ", (p+i)->x);}
    //free(p);
    free(p+1);
    //free(p+2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. I am setting aside memory for three structures with pointers `p, p+1, p+2` all returned by `realloc`. Why can't I call `free()` on them?

Comment: (sorry, I deleted my comment because of Vlad's answer). The reason why is because you are calling ```realloc()``` several times on the same pointer. In the end, you don't have 3 free-able pointers, you still have one, the block is just larger than it was before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the loop you declared the pointer p

```
struct s *p = NULL;
```

So after the loop it will store the address of the last reallocated memory.

To free the allocated memory you need just to write

```
free( p );
```

The expression `p + 1` points to the second element of the dynamically allocated array that was not allocated dynamically. It is the whole array that was allocated dynamically.